# Detect OS by HID device

Tags: keyboard, operating-system, usb, hid

I have a HID keyboard stack on my microcontroller, I have a question, whether HID device after plug-in obtains some information about operating system it is connected to?

Comment: Why would it need to?

Comment: I need to so I'm asking if maybe it does.. because I need to detect the OS my device is connecting to

Comment: Why? The HID protocol is sufficient for the keyboard/device to work with any OS that supports it. So, once again, why?

Comment: after plug-in my device sends specific keys and under Windows OS it is needed to send eg. CTRL+L but if it will be connected to Mac OS it should be CMD+L

Comment: I'm not sure that's a use case HID was designed for. Read the specs, Wikipedia has links to them. Maybe you'll find something. Or maybe not.

Comment: Probably it's not, but I was curious

Answer (score 2):

Not directly, but you can figure it out in the early handshake process between the USB devices via the Configuration Descriptors.

Check out these links:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/30362736/759341
- https://www.google.com/patents/US20120054372
- http://www.usb.org/developers/hidpage/HID1_11.pdf