# What data can a HID device receive?

Tags: keyboard, hid

I am designing a USB keyboard with special capabilities. What information can such a HID device receive from the host?

Can I via USB:

- Read data from a form on the screen?
- Find out what OS the user is on?
- Find out if there's been an error message?
- Even 'know' what's going on visually on the screen, i.e. what program is selected or whether the program is windowed or fullscreen?

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The device can't get any of this information from a standard driver that the operating system supplies because that would be a security issue. It *can* receive any information that your own driver or application sends it. There are many ways to communicate with it - your device could present multiple interfaces (which will appear as separate devices), multiple endpoints, or use the control channel. You will definitely need to study the [spec](http://www.usb.org/developers/hidpage/HID1_11.pdf), and I also found [this tutorial](http://www.usbmadesimple.co.uk/index.html) helpful.

I have done something similar and used the control channel to exchange feature data with a Windows application (over the standard Windows driver). On Windows, the API calls are [`HidD_SetFeature()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543402(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`HidD_GetFeature()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542426(v=vs.85).aspx).

On the device side, my hardware ran embedded Linux and I used the [GadgetFS library](http://www.linux-usb.org/gadget/) to create a user-mode driver - much easier to debug than a kernel driver.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you'll run into issues if you try this with a normal HID. However, there is a project called the [USB Rubber Ducky](https://github.com/hak5darren/USB-Rubber-Ducky/wiki). From their description:

```
The USB Rubber Ducky isn't your ordinary HID (Human Interface Device). 
Coupled with a powerful 60 MHz 32-bit processor and a simple scripting language
```

The `USB Rubber Ducky` looks like a usb-device and is recognized as a HID, but is programmable. You can make a small script that will be typed onto the screen which will allow you to performs the queries you seek.

With the `USB Rubber Ducky` you can:

- Read data from a form on the screen? **Yes**
- Find out what OS the user is on? **Yes**
- Find out if there's been an error message? **Yes**
- Even 'know' what's going on visually on the screen, i.e. what program is selected or whether the program is windowed or fullscreen? **Yes**

  *If you aren't hoping to buy this device, at least their firmware is on github so it can provide you a starting point*